# Web app to write data from shared hosting webpage to firebase firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I tried of finding way to write data  to firestore from shared hosting web page,

***Not many tutorials for firestore on Google so***

**right now I am updating/writing data/docs through my android app admin panel but it hard to do in mobile**

Tried for creating web page as per [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=0) and [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/?authuser=0#0)

the code labs days

```
What you'll need
The IDE/text editor of your choices such as WebStorm, Atom or Sublime.
npm which typically comes with NodeJS.
A console.
A browser such as Chrome.
The sample code. See next step for this.
```

so as per google cod lab npm / nodejs is required

But firesbase docs say nothing,
even though tried on shared Linux hosting (Siteground) as per firebase docs
But no results

***my question is now***

> - is it possible to create a web app to write data/documents on plain shared Linux hostings (like blue hsost/sitegroung.com etc..)
> - is it possible to develop web page without node js to write data/docs to firestore on shared Linux hosting?

Comment: Answer to your questions below. But if you're having problems making Cloud Firestore in your web app, you're likely better helped if you show the [minimal steps that allow us to recreate the problem that you have](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it is quite useful). Providing such an MCVE is the best way to ensure we can help you efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a web app to write data/documents on plain shared Linux hostings?

Yes. You can host your web app anywhere. The connection is made directly from the web page in the user's browser to Cloud Firestore, so no special requirements are placed on the host.

> is it possible to develop web page without node js to write data/docs to firestore on shared Linux hosting?

Yes. Node.js is not required to use Cloud Firestore within your web app, and it only used in the codelab to deploy to Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Is this still true? I tried using Firebase and I was locked to localhost and firebase hosting.

Comment: As far as I know this is still true today. But if you think you've found an alternative approach, please post it as another answer - so others can benefit from your experience.